# ROBLOX Like Camera Controls C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have looked over the internet for a Camera Script like the one in ROBLOX. But i can't seem to find one. Can anyone help me with this?
Btw i'm using Unity 2017.3

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: this might help you though : (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOTEg91eXAc)[Roblox Camera tuts.]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I will try to help you out. Please keep in mind though:

> Generally questions like this will receive negative feedback as the question isn't specific enough and you haven't provided any attempts or code for us to work with.
>   People sometimes see this as a "can you do my work for me" scenario.

You are new so I want to take a stab at helping you out regardless.
I hope this helps you and potentially others.
I've included code comments for clarity.

### TO USE THIS YOU MUST

- create a new script in unity (C#) and attach it to your 'Player' GameObject
- edit the script, and paste the below code into the editor
- save the script and return to the editor, new settings will appear for the script
- modify the settings to your liking and **DRAG** in the camera to the "The Camera" field

[Edit]

Probably worth mentioning, I also added a pause function to unlock the cursor and return control to the mouse, this can be built upon or removed as needed.

The script:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class ThirdPersonCamera : MonoBehaviour {
        //define some constants
        private const float LOW_LIMIT = 0.0f;
        private const float HIGH_LIMIT = 85.0f;

        //these will be available in the editor
        public GameObject theCamera;
        public float followDistance = 5.0f;
        public float mouseSensitivityX = 4.0f;
        public float mouseSensitivityY = 2.0f;
        public float heightOffset = 0.5f;

        //private variables are hidden in editor
        private bool isPaused = false;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            //place the camera and set the forward vector to match player
            theCamera.transform.forward = gameObject.transform.forward;
            //hide the cursor and lock the cursor to center
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            //if escape key (default) is pressed, pause the game (feel free to change this)
            if (Input.GetButton("Cancel"))
            {
                //flip the isPaused state, hide/unhide the cursor, flip the lock state
                isPaused = !isPaused;
                Cursor.visible = !Cursor.visible;
                Cursor.lockState = Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked ?
                CursorLockMode.None : CursorLockMode.Locked;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

            if(!isPaused)
            {
                //if we are not paused, get the mouse movement and adjust the camera
                //position and rotation to reflect this movement around player
                Vector2 cameraMovement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"),Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

                //first we place the camera at the position of the player + height offset
                theCamera.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(0,heightOffset,0);

                //next we adjust the rotation based on the captured mouse movement
                //we clamp the pitch (X angle) of the camera to avoid flipping
                //we also adjust the values to account for mouse sensitivity settings
                theCamera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
                    Mathf.Clamp(theCamera.transform.eulerAngles.x + cameraMovement.y * mouseSensitivityY, LOW_LIMIT, HIGH_LIMIT),
                    theCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y + cameraMovement.x * mouseSensitivityX, 0);

                //then we move out to the desired follow distance
                theCamera.transform.position -= theCamera.transform.forward * followDistance;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be inactive, but here is one that moves on right click:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float LOW_LIMIT = 0.0f;
    private const float HIGH_LIMIT = 85.0f;

    public GameObject theCamera;
    public float followDistance = 5.0f;
    public float mouseSensitivityX = 4.0f;
    public float mouseSensitivityY = 2.0f;
    public float heightOffset = 0.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        theCamera.transform.forward = gameObject.transform.forward;
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            Vector2 cameraMovement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
            theCamera.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(0, heightOffset, 0);
            theCamera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(
                Mathf.Clamp(theCamera.transform.eulerAngles.x + cameraMovement.y * mouseSensitivityY, LOW_LIMIT, HIGH_LIMIT),
                theCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y + cameraMovement.x * mouseSensitivityX, 0);
            theCamera.transform.position -= theCamera.transform.forward * followDistance;
        }
    }
}
```